# PasswordField validation in SilverStripe

Tags: validation, passwords, silverstripe

I have a member in my project called Customer. I need to validate PasswordField.

I created a function in my page containing the PasswordField as below

```
function getValidator() {

    $data = $this->loadData();              

    if (@$data['Password']->minLength(7)) {
        return $this->validationError('Password', 'Password field should contain minimum 7 charactors', 'bad');         
    }   
}
```

This does not give any result. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove that ugly `@` from your code and watch that beautiful error message. Error supression is a real bad practice, you should avoid that
2. There is already a class `PasswordValidator` which is used by the `Member` object and can check the minimum length of a password. ([See API Docs for PasswordValdiator](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PasswordValidator.html#_minLength))

If you show us more code I can try to help you implementing it right.

Is your `Customer` object a subclass of Member? Where is the password changed? What FormField is used for Password? There is also a [ConfirmedPasswordField](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ConfirmedPasswordField.html) showing two masked fields for matching passwords where you can set a minlength.

So, assuming you save your password in a field called `Password` you could set up the field e.g.

```
$passwordField = ConfirmedPasswordField('Password', 'Choose a password');
$passwordField->minLength = 7; //there is no setter method for that right now
```

Then add $passwordField to your `FieldList` e.g using

```
$fields->push($passwordField);
```

Comment: when i give a length for the minlength in  ConfirmedPasswordField.php  it works fine. Is there any other way to validate with a minlength for password field without changing minLengthin in ConfirmedPasswordField.php.  customer is an object

Comment: Hi, i modified my answer with demo code how to use ConfirmedPasswordField in your FieldList. If it works for you feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: is there a way to set minlength to paswordfield at the same place itis created rather giving a minlength in ConfirmedPasswordField.php. page.

Comment: @user3358839 just commenting on the minimum password lenght that you have there :) http://blog.codinghorror.com/your-password-is-too-damn-short/

Comment: @user3358839 - If this answer has solved your problem please mark it as accepted. Also, if you think it is a good answer then an up vote is nice too.